# "Недопустимый вызывающий объект" при вызове функции

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть следующая функция:

```
function SendDataToController(d) {   
    $.ajax({
        url: "Index",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "JSON",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: d,
        success: function(result) {
            alert("Data was send to the controller");
        },
        error: function(err) {
            alert("Error: data was not send to the controller");
        }
    });
    alert(d);  
}
```

Она расположена в файле *SendDataToController.js* и вызывается в другой функции (файл *SendPassportToService.js*):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tr').click(function() {        
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.soap({
            url: "http://localhost:8123/C_M_Service/",
            method: "OrdersByPassport",
            SOAPAction: "http://localhost:8123/C_M_Service/OrdersByPassport",            
            soap11: true,
            data: '<OrdersByPassport xmlns="http://C_M_Service">\
                    <passport>' + id + '</passport>\
                    </OrdersByPassport>',
            error: function (soapresponse) {
                alert("Oh no is error: " + soapresponse.toString());
            },
            success: function (result) {                               
                alert("OK " + result);
                SendDataToController(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Добавил скрипты к странице следующим образом:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.soap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="SendDataToController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="SendPassportToService.js"></script>
```

При срабатывании скрипта из *SendPassportToService.js* появляется ошибка *"Недопустимый вызывающий объект"* в функции `SendDataToController`. Как исправить данную ошибку?

**Обновление**

Данные доходят до указанного адреса, так что обмен данными есть. Ошибка происходит в файле *jquery-2.1.3.js*:

> Необработанное исключение в строке 8453, столбце 4 в http://localhost:61327/jquery-2.1.3.js

Браузер IE10.

Comment: Вопрос только в том, как протестировать ваш код, учитывая, что доступа к вашему `localhost` у нас, конечно, нет. В [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agzbwx9y/) (данный код внизу) "всё плохо" на данный момент.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, эта проблема воспроизводится только в IE? Хотелось бы также знать на какую строчку указывает ошибка и возникает ли она в вашем коде или коде библиотек?

Comment: Ошибка в IE только? Если не только, то как ругаются нормальные бразуеры? Если только, то какие-нибудь режимы совместимости включены? Методом пристального вглядывания мне тут сложно сказать в чем ошибка

Comment: В данный момент я использую Internet Explorer. Так ругается, собственно, не браузер.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Точно сказать что именно падает без нормального респонса от сервера сложно, но судя по всему проблема в том, что вы берете результат вызова `$.soap` и пытаетесь передать его как json (вызовом `$.ajax`). Результат вызова `$.soap` - это скорее всего `SOAPResponse` с вложенным `XMLDocument` - т.е. достаточно сложный объект, с методами и прочим.

А JQuery надо передать его как JSON - строку. JQuery преобразует объект в строку достаточно тупо - просто бежит по всем его свойствам, заходя во вложенные объекты. Если какое-то свойство - это функция, то JQuery вызывает ее и сериализует результат. Это делается как раз в строке 8453. Вот только вызывается функция не в контексте объекта, а просто в текущем контексте:

```
add = function( key, value ) {
            // If value is a function, invoke it and return its value
            value = jQuery.isFunction( value ) ? value() : ( value == null ? "" : value );
            s[ s.length ] = encodeURIComponent( key ) + "=" + encodeURIComponent( value );
        };
```

вызов `value()` - это и есть проблемное место. В JS нельзя просто так взять и вызвать функцию. Если у вас есть объект `obj` и у него есть метод `someMethod()`, то вот такой вызов валиден:

```
obj.someMethod();
```

Но если вы напишете в коде

```
var m = obj.someMethod;
m();
```

То на самом деле выполнится следующий код:

```
var m = obj.someMethod;
this.m();
```

т.е. метод полностью отрывается от первоначального контекста. и если у this не окажется метода m, то в IE9+ он упадет с ошибкой "Недопустимый вызывающий объект". Потому такой код скорее всего ошибочен - очень маловероятно что someMethod ожидает у себя внутри какой-то левый this вместо obj.

Правильный способ вызывать такие методы - `call` или `bind`:

```
 m.call(obj);
 // или
 var m = obj.someMethod.bind(obj);
 m();
```

JQuery рассчитывает что если при сериализации в объекте и будут свойства, ссылающиеся на методы - то они будут прибайнджены к нужному контексту.

В вашем случае код jquery править не стоит, нужно просто передавайть в ajax объект попроще, а не весь `SOAPResponse`.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ! В скрипт передаётся строка, да и в alert("OK " + result); принятые данные без проблем выводятся как строковое представление XML.